# Topic to Topic communication (Google cloud pub-sub)

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I have topic1 in project1, topic2 in project2. I need to publish a message from topic1 to topic2.

Can we publish the message directly to the topic2 using pub-sub configuration from topic1 without writing any code in any programming language, also without creating any subscriber.

In summary: Is it possible to communicate between the topics directly in Google Cloud Pub-Sub?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to communicate directly from topic1 to topic2. You will need to create a subscription on topic1. You can either write a simple subscriber that reads messages from that subscription and then immediately publishes to topic2 or you could use the [Dataflow template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#cloudpubsubtocloudpubsub) that does this.

Comment: Thanks! Kamal Aboul-Hosn